# How can I count Facebook Connect button clicks on my site

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbconnect, fbjs

When the user clicks Connect with Facebook button rendered with FBJS code:

```
<fb:login-button>Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

I want to record this click to my server. I should find a way to get this click with JavaScript and then I'll pass it to my server via a function. So how can I run a function when the user clicks this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign onclick property to a fb:login-button.

`<fb:login-button onclick="bravo()">Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>`